# How to generate multiple files from r script function with knitr

Tags: r

I would like to generate a number of reports from an r script. I would like to avoid the duplication needed when compiling from rmd files and I'd like to generate the reports from the r script itself if possible.

The script has a function which should generate each report from a list of dataframes where each report represents the processing of one dataframe. I just can't understand how to generate each report separately. At the moment the report shows all of the dataframes in one file

The original script is long so I have provided a minimal version below.

```
    structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("boo", 
    "saa", "yaew"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
    1L), .Label = c("mfds", "shu", "ren"), class = "factor"), c = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L), .Label = c("22", "23", "5345"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", 
    "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

    ReportOp<-function(n) { 
  this_is_a_name <- n; 
  this_is_my_data <- ldf[[n]] 

  #' ---
  #' author: Me
  #' date:
  #' ---

  #+results='asis', echo=FALSE
  knitr::kable(this_is_my_data, digits = 2)
  #'
}
```

At the moment I am just generating the report with everything in it using the`compile notebook` button in R studio.

I tried using `knitr::spin` on the above script as follows from a separate file:

```
library(knitr)
o=spin('/Users/sebastianzeki/Desktop/UntitledTBB.R')
knit2html(o,output="/Users/sebastianzeki/Desktop/out.html")
```

but again I only get one report outputted rather than three.

Comment: I use a parameterized R markdown document for this purpose, then using a wrapper around `rmarkdown::render()` render reports iterating over combinations of parameters (using `lapply`, `map`, `do` or whatever suits your fancy).

Comment: @Jake Kaupp - do you mean I should insert rmarkdown::render() after names(x)? What i don't understand is what to put in the markdown document...Confused...

Comment: 1. Create a report.rmd with parameters in the YAML. The report should call the main dataset and the parameters subset it as per your choice.  2. Use `rmarkdown::render()` to render the report.rmd with your parameter selections via the `apply` family (or write a wrapper and use `apply`).  I suggest reading the docs for `rmarkdown::render()` to get everything sorted.

Comment: @Jake Kaupp. The problem is that the parameters change so I was kind of hoping that I could output directly from the function without needing to create .rmd files.

Comment: You would make a single markdown file and pass the parameters to that through `render()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would make a single [rmarkdown parameterized report](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html). Define the parameters in the YAML.   You render the report by passing the parameters to `rmarkdown::render()` in a list.

You'd run this over multiple sets of parameters by various means in r, loops, the `apply` family (`mapply` in this case), `dplyr::do`, or the `purrr:map()` functions.  In this example, I use `purrr::pmap()`.

**Report.Rmd**

````
---
title: "`r sprintf('mtcars %s vs. %s', params$variable1, params$variable2)`"
output: html_document
params:
  variable1: "mpg"
  variable2: "cyl"
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
```
#Plot
Crazy report text!

```{r cars}
ggplot(mtcars, aes_(x = as.name(params$variable1), y = as.name(params$variable2))) +
  geom_point()
```
````

**Render Function**

```
render_report <- function(var1, var2) {

  template <- "path_to/Report.Rmd"

  out_file <- sprintf("report %s vs. %s", var2, var1)

  parameters <- list(variable1 = var1,
                     variable2 = var2)

    rmarkdown::render(template,
                      output_file = out_file,
                      params = parameters)
  invisible(TRUE)
}
```

**Running over multiple parameters.**

```
library(purrr)

params_list <- list(list("mpg","mpg","mpg"),
                    list("drat","wt","qsec"))

pmap(params_list, render_report)
```

**Output**

Three html files, each named by the parameters, each with the scatterplot according to the parameters.

1. drat vs mpg
   [image]
2. qsec vs mpg
   [image]
3. wt vs mpg
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was unclear on some of the finer points of parameterized knitr reports.

Comment: I have a slightly different problem. Can you please help? With your approach, I tried to create a single report but with multiple pages with multiple plots/dataframe etc (instead creating multiple reports as in this case). I have included a 'for' loop in the `.Rmd` file which loops over multiple objects and print it. However, I am getting multiple reports instead of a single report with multiple pages

Comment: For less proficient people (like myself), note the following tips if you have problems: Make sure that for your `Report.Rmd `, you have set the right directory. This can be done via `setwd("C://your_path")`). Next, save the first code chunk as an `.Rmd` file as described. Then, to have a script, save code chunks 2 and 3 to a separate file in the same folder (`run.R` for example). I wasn't able to make the `run.R` as `run.Rmd` in order to use knitr but running the code chunk by itself worked. Perhaps this is an issue with the working directory?

Comment: @NarendraSahu perhaps use book down with global parameters?