# R knitr report with multiple pages

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, purrr

I am facing difficulty creating multi-page report for multiple R objects (in the same output file). For example, if I give a list of 2 dataframes to the function and calls the `.Rmd` file, it should produce a single report with 2 dataframes in 2 pages.

Currently, I am not able to produce a 2-page report, instead, it is creating 2 files. I want to achieve this by not explicitly running the `.Rmd` file but through a function call.

Here is my code:

**test.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
params:
  variable1: list
  variable2: path
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
````

````
```{r, results='asis'}
my_list <- list(params$variable1)
for (i in 1:length(my_list)){
  print(knitr::kable(my_list[i]))
}
````

Here is the **function file code**

```
library(purrr)
library(knitr)
render_report <- function(PageList, RmdPath) {
  out_file <- 'my_document'
  parameters <- list(
                     variable1 = PageList,
                     variable2 = RmdPath)
  
  rmarkdown::render(RmdPath,
                    'pdf_document',
                    output_file = out_file,
                    params = parameters)
  invisible(TRUE)
}

df1 = data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
df2 = data.frame(x=rnorm(15), y=rnorm(15), z = rnorm(15))
my_list = list(df1, df2)

param_list = list(my_list, "C:/Users/naren/Documents/test.Rmd")
#################################################################################################

purrr::pmap(param_list, render_report)
```

If I just run the `.Rmd` file, it is producing single output with 2 R objects in it, however, through this approach I am not able to achieve this.
I have taken this approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525300/how-to-generate-multiple-files-from-r-script-function-with-knitr)

Comment: It might help to better understand the ultimate goal, as this feels a bit like you've outlined a goal constrained by the technical path you've started, but that your underlying goal may be approached an entirely different and simpler way. I'd approach this with an R Markdown page break. Or if you really wanted to start with two distinct PDF files and then combine then, I'd rely on the R package `pdftools` and `pdf_combine`. Any issues with that?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create a function where I can pass the following
(a.) what needs to be printed on 1st page i.e. title, author, date etc.
(b.) list of R objects (can be dataframe or plots) along with their title/footers etc that needs to be printed on separate pages after the 1st page.
As you can see, I need to print only 1 pdf/word file with all the R objects printed on separate pages along with the usual 1st page (not multiple pdfs/word documents).