# How to pass a value to Rmd file while rendering from a R script?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an Rmd file where I am generating some ggplots by retrieving data from a database server. I am trying to call this Rmd file by a loop and generate separate pdf files. For this I need to pass an unique value to the Rmd file in each iteration of the loop, this value is needed to access data from DB in the Rmd file. Also want to name the generated pdf files by the value I want to pass.

I have tried something similar to this resource in the R script:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rmarkdown-render.html

```
for (state in state.name) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    'input.Rmd', output_file = paste0(state, '.pdf')
  )
}
```

But this isn't working properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate multiple files from r script function with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525300/how-to-generate-multiple-files-from-r-script-function-with-knitr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `render` takes arguments `output_file` and `params`. Output file is the file to be saved to and params are what you pass to the Markdown code.

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("File.rmd", 
       output_file="file.pdf", 
       params=list(text="print this"))
```

And then in your RMarkdown file you can access the parameter you passed via `params$parametername`.

```
---
params:
  text: "what"
---

print(params$text)
```

For your code, you would do something like the following in your R code and Rmarkdown code, respectively:

```
for (state in state.name) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    'input.Rmd', output_file = paste0(state, '.pdf'), params=list(state=state)
  )
}
```

```
---
params:
  state: "what"
---

params$state
```

Comment: params=list(state=state) isn't passing the parameter from R script.

Comment: Does the first example work? Are the states all good? `for (state in state.name) print(state)` in R script. What happens if you try to do `print(params$state)` inside a code chunk `{r}print(params$state)` in R markdown?

Comment: It worked now actually! Just needed to print states in Rmd file as `r params$state`.